# How to get rid of black arrowheads in right bottom corner of excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a file with Excel 97-2003 (.xls) version. When this file is opened in Excel 2013, shows black arrowheads in right bottom corner of the cell. These arrows are only in cells B3:J3 and F4. All these cells contains integer numbers. To get an idea what I want to convey please have a look at following image.

[image: Click here to see the screenshot of excel sheet]

**Things i have tried to remove arrowheads**

1. Clear content and insert data again. (Arrow head is still there even if I remove data.)
2. Clear formatting.
3. Use Format painter and format the cells having arrowhead with the format of cells not having arrowhead.
4. Deleting the cells. (If I delete the cells, these arrows get shifted to cells above it)
5. Removing the conditional formatting from these cells.

Interesting thing is when I try to print the sheets the arrowheads vanish in print preview. I want to get rid of the black arrowheads (or triangles) in the excel sheet.

Thanks in advance... :)

**Edit:**
Things i have tried to remove arrowheads in addition to above mentioned

1. "Remove Arrows" from "Formulas" tab

Comment: could they be inserted shapes? go to the home ribbon, find&select, select objects, and try to select them.

Comment: @PA. Those are not inserted objects, I checked that as well. Arrowhead tip is fixed at the right bottom corner of cell. And these cannot be selected and deleted.

Comment: Could they be error-checking indicators pointing to the cell below right from the cell they appear in?

Comment: In Page Layout ► Page Setup, do you have a **Background** or **Delete Background** command? If the latter, the arrows are simply a 'watermark' image.

Comment: I am into excel for more than 8 years and this never happened to me. My life is a joke!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'home' tab on the ribbon, click 'select & find', then 'selection pane'.

If there is anything in this pane, select and delete it and that will probably remove the arrows.

Also, in the 'Formulas' tab in the ribbon, click 'Remove arrows'

Answer (score 0):

1. Function Key and F5 at the same time in the cell in which the black arrowhead appears.
2. Click on Special.
3. Click on Objects.
4. A gray circle will appear.
5. Hit the delete key

and the black arrowhead will disappear